# Why am I getting a t-value = infinity or missing t value

Tags: sas, statistics, finance, economics

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an infinity or missing t-value for regression analysis (GARCH). It's a very large data set.

Thanks

Updated:

I want to add the code and the result for 150 observations (as I am away from my PC I cannot upload the main result for a large dataset.

My code is:

```
 proc autoreg data=work;
 model y = / garch=(p=1,q=1);
 hetere x z a;
 run;
```

My result is:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code and the log?  My assumption is the MLE is not converging.

Comment: My code is:
 
     proc autoreg data=work;
     model y = / garch=(p=1,q=1);
     hetere x z a;
     run;

Comment: Your AR1 estimate is almost 0. It probably didn't converge. Check your log.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a infinity t-value because your standard error is zero.

I would guess that if your standard error is zero then the problem might be on the data.